# How to unset value from json encode array using php

Tags: php, json

How can i delete value from json encode array using php. here is my json format.

```
{"1":["fileid",time],"2":["fileid",time],"3":["fileid",time]}
```

And here is my php code. but nothing is delete. i want to remove whole array value ex

```
"3":["fileid",time]
```

when function execute.

```
<?php
$filename = "test.json";
$fopen = fopen($filename,"r");
$fgets = fgets($fopen);
fclose($fopen);
$decode = json_decode($fgets,true);
foreach($decode as $post){
    $dif = time() - $post[1];
    if($dif > 5){
        foreach ((array)$post[0] as $val => $v) {
            echo  $id = $v.'<br>';
        }
        unset($decode[1]);   
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the code is doing the right thing, you dont rewrite the file after the changes?

Comment: No value is still there after execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index, rather than always unsetting occurance `1`. So change your `foreach` as below and use that index `$i` on the original array

You can also simplify the file read to `file_get_contents()`

```
$buf = file_get_contents("test.json");
$array = json_decode($buf,true);

foreach($array as $i => $post){
    $dif = time() - $post[1];
    if($dif > 5){
        unset($array[$i]);  
    }
}
file_put_contents("test2.json",json_encode($array));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you modify it little i have more values inside that json in concatenate or string, i want to get separate value to call them inside function as single id.

Comment: Don't toally understand, can you show a sample of the data and what you want to do with it

Comment: ```{"1":["fileid",time],"2":["fileid",time],"3":["fileid",time]}``` suppose these are the values, but it returns all ```$post[1]``` values as a single string but i have pass single fileid as a string in my function. All File ids are joined as a single string.

Comment: Still not sure I understand. I see no function, so maybe if you ADD this next part to your question with an example of what you mean

Comment: I'm getting data in this format ```fileidtimefileidtimefileidtime``` it is return value like this i want to store single value in var instead of whole data, so how to seprate values using foreach loop after ```if($dif > 5){``` this. i need only fileid or ```$post[0]``` value. Hope you understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: Well you see I dont see you doing anything like that in the code you show, if you EDIT your question and ADD this code you are talking about I will be able to work out what you want to do I am pretty sure

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time mate, i build that what i need.

Comment: So you only want to echo some data, IF the $dif is greater than 5.

Comment: But what do you actually want to print?

Comment: I want to delete data after sometime, but now i fixed and its working.